# Is there a hive property to delete scratch dir created for a table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table - `table_1 -- 1.9Billion records -- orc format -- 229G size`

I have a script to create `table2` by joining table1 and `<some other table>`.

```
table2 - 30K records -- orc format -- 229G size
```

when I check the hdfs path for table2, I could see dir name - scratchdir and it occupies 220G of space.

```
[root@host ~]$ hadoop fs -du -s -h /db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2
220.8 G  /db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2
[root@lnx1397 ~]$ ls -ltr /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2
total 2943
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       2 Sep 16 23:29 _scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-17
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       2 Sep 16 23:29 _scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-18
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       2 Sep 16 23:30 _scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-19
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       2 Sep 16 23:42 _scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-20
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root       5 Sep 16 23:45 _scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3010663 Sep 17 00:25 000000_0

[root@host ~]$ du -sh /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/*
2.9M    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/000000_0
221G    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/_scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-1
1.0K    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/_scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-17
1.0K    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/_scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-18
1.0K    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/db_name.db/managed/table2/_scratchdir_hive_2021-09-16_23-29-42_576_3081873685168820741-19
1.0K    /mapr/mapre04p//db_name/data/db/receipt
```

> database volume is 1TB, i have script to drop table1 but the jobs are
> failing with disk quota exceeded error due to high volume of scratch
> dir

is there an hive property or configuration to remove these `scratchdir`